# Sorting Methods and Write results to textFile

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with sorting methods and random.  `Button1` Creates the parameter randomize numbers, size, and the maximum number limit to work from. Then according to what linear method is chosen, `Button2` Sorts those numbers and then uses a stopwatch to time how long it took.  I am currently implementing away to show : `sort method`, `size`, `time_tosort` and `number of operations`  in a text file. So I have the first part done, when program loads I have prompted the user to create a file for where the results will be stored.

What ways can I go about appending the results into the textFile and averaging the results ? Also would I need to add a button to close the write function after user finishes sorting?

**Example of desired format:**  `sort method`, `size`, `time_tosort` and `number of operations`

```
Linear 10000 .9 100,000,000
Linear 10000 .8 110,000,000
Linear 10000 .75 150,000,000
Linear 10000 .50 70,000,000
Linear 10000 .7375  107,500,000 ---- AVG
```

**CODE**

```
namespace sortMachine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Save()
        {
            var saveReport = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveReport.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";
            var result = saveReport.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.Cancel || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(saveReport.FileName))
                return;

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(saveReport.FileName))
            {
                writer.Write(textBox1.Text);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }

        private List<string> messages = new List<string>() { "Linear", "Bubble", "Index", "Other" };
        private int clickCount = 0;

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

            }
            else if (textBox7.Text == "Bubble")
            {
            }
            else if (textBox7.Text == "Index")
            {
            }
            else if (textBox7.Text == "Other")
            {
            }
            else if (textBox7.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input a sorting method");
            }
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Save();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox7.Text = messages[clickCount];
        clickCount++;
        if (clickCount == messages.Count)
            clickCount = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you rename your controls? For example, `textBox7` could be `keyTextBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look through all the code, but you have <strike>two</strike> **three** parts to your question:

**How can I sort/average the results?**  Once you have a `List` of your results, you can call [`.Average()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx), [`.OrderBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), and so on on them.  These are part of the `System.Linq` namespace. (Full list of useful functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx).)

**How can I output it to a text file?** Take a look at the `File.IO` namespace.  [Here's a guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304430).

**How can I get the data for the result?** Your best bet is to create a new class:

```
class SortData
{
   public string SortMethod;
   public int Size;
   public TimeSpan TimeToSort;
   public int NumberOfOperations;
}
```

Create a `List<SortData>` and put all your results in there, each as a `new SortData()`.  Then you can do something along these lines:

```
foreach (var data in myList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(SortMethod + "\t" + Size + "\t" + TimeToSort + "\t" + NumberOfOperations);
}
```

You'll need to output to the file instead of the console, but the idea is the same.

Comment: +1 Thank you, much clear. Could you show me how to place in a list my results(`sort method`, `size`, `time_tosort` and `number of operations`)?

Comment: @charliecodex23 - I added a suggestion, but that's about as far as I can go for you. You should be able to take it from there.